# Maven: create a jar from a package of a larger project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, jar

In my maven would like to create a jar with the only compiled classes from the package  `org.lory.ejb.commons` as you can see here:

[image]

because these classes are common between ejb core project and client project. I am trying with maven assembly plugin where my assembly descriptor is:

```
<assembly>
<id>commons</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/target/classes/</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>org/lory/ejb/commons/**</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

And the portion of my pom.xml is

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It seems that a jar is generated by the package path inside it is not respected (it is not the same of the contained compiled classes). In fact, if I try to import it into the other project, Eclipse does not let me use it:

[image]

Which is the right way to use it?
Thank you

**UPDATE**
This is my common project
[image]

and pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>lory-ejb-commons</groupId>
<artifactId>lory-ejb-commons</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>lory-ejb-commons</name>
<modules>
    <module>lory-ejb</module>
</modules>
```

This is the pom.xml of the other project (from which commons package was removed)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>lory-ejb-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>lory-ejb-commons</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>lory-ejb</artifactId>
<name>lory-ejb</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>lory-ejb-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>lory-ejb-commons</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

But it still does not work. After cleaning and installing both project, I've got this error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project lory-ejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project lory-ejb-commons:lory-ejb:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact lory-ejb-commons:lory-ejb-commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

In the child project I can't even import commons package as jar, it just sees it as a directory and even if I can import classes in source code, java compiler still says

> The import org.lory.ejb.commons.OperationOutcome cannot be 
>    resolved

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you are trying to create a jar file (a module) that only contains a subset of the code- but you are doing it in an unconventional way.

The main way to do that in Maven is to create a parent project (a maven project with `pom` packaging); add a module called `common` where you put the common code (all code from your `org.lory.ejb.commons` package); and add other `client` and `server` modules where you put the client and server code respectively. Both the `client` and `server` modules will have a dependency to `common`.

---

BTW, note that using modules is also easier- eg. using Eclipse you can simply create a new Maven project with pom packaging; add maven modules (with `jar` packagin) to it; and move code to the right module

---

**EDIT**
Projects with packaging `pom` do not produce jar files when built. That's why you have the error: *Could not find artifact lory-ejb-commons:lory-ejb-commons:* **jar** *:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT* . (that's because a `pom` project is special, it is not intended to contain code; so you should have no code directly in it).

You should name your parent project eg. `lory-ejb-parent`, create another module called `common` under it, and put the common code there; and have the `lory-ejb` module depend on the `common` module.

Also, Eclipse manages dependencies across maven-based projects automatically, so there is no need to change anything under project->Java Build Path

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice. I am afraid I am doing it in an uncoventional way because I have neved used Maven before. At work we build with ant+ivy. I started using Maven on my own because someone suggested me to study it. ehm, where can I find and example of what you are talking about?

Comment: in example (found by googling "github maven module example",,) here https://github.com/jamesward/maven-multi-module-example . You can import->import as Maven project into eclipse the parent project; it will detect the modules and import them as separate projects, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I am gonna have a look!

Comment: would you please have a look at my updated question? I really can't make it work.

Comment: @SagittariusA yup